# HTTP Streaming: what realizations of Push Technology are available?

Tags: c++, http, http-streaming

I'm currently in search of an usable realizations of http [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). At least it must support *channel subscription* and *channel publication*.

What convenient implementations in C++ (or C) are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing that comes to mind (in C++) that supports server push and self contains a httpd is  [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). It's actually remarkably easy to get installed, compile a program, and get running.  I didn't have any Qt background.  If you do that will make it even easier for you.